# Blazor WebAssembly no longer builds successfully

Tags: asp.net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Each time I try to run Blazor WebAssembly, I get this error

> /Users/mac/Projects/test412421/test412421/Client/Program.cs(40,40): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'App' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246) (test412421.Client)

Can anyone help? I've re-installed the SDKs and Visual Studio several times

Comment: App usually refers to the default `App.razor` which is normally in the client project, but you may have moved yours - make sure your program.cs has the correct `using` directives to reference your `App` class.

Comment: Also check you haven't created a class or folder called `App` somewhere.